# Java awt.list ActionListener single click

Tags: java, list, awt, actionlistener

I have a list of cities.
When you click on a city it shows the current time, date etc.. for the city

However it only updates when i double click on the city
How would I go about changing it to a single click

Thanks

```
 @Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
    Set<String> countries = regionMap.get(listRegion.getSelectedItem());
    listSubRegion.removeAll();
    for(String country : countries)
    {
        listSubRegion.add(country);
    }

    selectedRegion = listRegion.getSelectedItem();

    listSubRegion.validate();
    listSubRegion.repaint();

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Can you put your  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
     {
      
      
     }
      overloaded moethod please?

Comment: I dont have a MouseEvent method. I assumed that itemStateChanged would work

Comment: You cannot change state of a "Choice" with one click. One click to drop-down menu one click to select the choice. Your city consists of many states like buildings ?

Comment: its an awt.list so you should be able to select it with one click. there is no drop-down menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
            // single click
            int index = theList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
            if (index >= 0) {
                Object o = theList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                ... do something ...            
            }
        }
    }
});
```